# How to fix continuous cleanups in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-onenote-2016

When I open a new note (<kbd>Win+N</kbd> or via the launcher) I get the message

> We're sorry. OneNote is cleaning up from the last time it was open. Please wait.

After a while a new note is opened. This happens at every new note.

I found a workaround: to delete the contents of `C:\users\%userprofile%\appdata\local\temp`. This fixes the issue **once**, that is at the next new note I have the error message again (and, again, the new note finally opens).

These operations are perfectly replicable (new note, error, clean Temp, new note starts ok, next new note has the error, clean up ... )

**Is there a proper fix for this issue?** I have the latest patches and the issue is present on the net for quite a long time already (at least since early 2015).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, even when creating a new workbook.

### Solution

It turned out that even when I created a new (local) notebook, some default locations were still pointing to a notebook located in the cloud.

Check this in `File -> Options -> Save & Backup -> Save`
Maybe one of these locations (for me it was Quick Notes Section) point to an unknown or cloud location. I changed this to a local location and the nagging cleaning popup was gone (just like my cloud sync, but I can live without it).

Answer (score 0):

Downlod the Sendto one note app from Microsfot and then update your printer within the product you are trying to send from

This fixd the problem straight away

https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/store/p/sendtoonenote/9mvjm1z9vwjd